# Twillio API: Join video conference without camera

Tags: javascript, video, twilio, twilio-api, video-conferencing

I am using https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js to run a video conference project.
I want to allow users to join without a camera. So, they can only use a mic.

With Twilio video conference, users can join video conferences without a camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the API docs this should be possible by setting `video = false` in the connect options, see the [twilio-video documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.13.1/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions).

In the quickstart example you're using you should overwrite it in the `const connectOptions` in `index.js` [here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/master/quickstart/src/index.js#L49).

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will check this